# React Native Drawer and Tab navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

My Drawer Navigation:

```
const DrawerNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Main" component={TabNavigator} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="About" component={AboutStackNavigator} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
};
```

In my Bottom Tab navigation i dont'vave menu item About. Thats why when I'm on About page, Bottom Tab Navigation disappears. How to make Bottom Tab Navigation always visible?

I already tried to make hidden menu item in Tab navigation but it's not possible as far as I understand

Comment: Are you using expo ?

Comment: Yes,  using expo

Comment: I think it's not possible to show TabNavigation all the time when the root navigator is a drawer component.  If you want to show tab navigation on every screen, you must use TabNavigation as the root navigator and add a tab as a menu and display the drawer navigation items in that tab screen like Facebook design